# Luajit load shared object from current working directory instead of default search path

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm using Luajit 2.0.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

I have a simple C library.

```
int five() {
    return 5;
}
```

I compile it like so

```
gcc -o five.so -shared -fPIC -Wall -Werror five.c
```

In the same directory I have a lua script

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.load("./five.so")

ffi.cdef([[
int five();
]])

print(ffi.C.five())
```

I've also tried it with an absolute path.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

local fh = assert(io.popen("pwd", "r"))
local cwd = assert(fh:read())

print(cwd)

ffi.load(cwd .. "/five.so")

ffi.cdef([[
int five();
]])

print(ffi.C.five())
```

When I run

```
luajit five.lua
```

I get this

```
luajit: five.lua:6: luajit: undefined symbol: five
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function '__index'
        five.lua:6: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x004044a0
```

How do I load a shared object in the current working directory in luajit?

Comment: Use `local lib = ffi.load( "./five.os" ); print( lib.five() )` or (on POSIX) `ffi.load( "./five.so", true ); print( ffi.C.five() )`. Have a look at the [ffi documentation](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html#ffi_C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. The reason is that `ffi.C` points to a namespace to access the standard C-runtime (plus some additional libraries depending on your OS). From LuaJIT docs:

> This is the default C library namespace [...] — note the uppercase
>   'C'. It binds to the default set of symbols or libraries on the target
>   system. These are more or less the same as a C compiler would offer by
>   default, without specifying extra link libraries.

If you want to call a C-function from an external library you need to:

1. Declare the function to use inside `ffi.cdef`, so LuaJIT knows how
   to call that function.
2. Import the external library and assign it to
   a Lua variable which serves as a namespace for the external
   function.
3. Actually call the function.

Your code can be reworked as:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

local lib = ffi.load("five")

ffi.cdef([[
   int five();
]])

print(lib.five())
```

<strike>In addition, it's not necessary to add `.os` suffix. To resolve library names, the `package.cpath` variable is used. It works like `package.path` variable. Question marks (?) are replaced by the library name.</strike>

```
$ luajit -e "print(package.cpath)"
./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so
```

Comment: `ffi.load` does **not** use the path templates in `package.cpath` but the OSes default shared library search path. This is why your example code doesn't work, and you need `ffi.load("./five.so")` instead. Also you **do** need the ".so" extension in this case, because `ffi.load` doesn't append the extension if the library name already contains a dot. See [ffi documentation](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html#ffi_load).

Comment: @siffiejoe Right, you're correct. I wrongly assumed `ffi.load` uses `package.cpath`. That said, the code sample I posted works (at least in my system). Since the library name is not a path, ".so" is appended, as explained in the FFI docs. Running the program with strace reveals the system tries to load the library from the current directory `open("lib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)      = 3`.  I don't know what's the reason for that though.

Comment: Maybe you have the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set (or you default shared library search path already contains the current working directory). Here I get "luajit: test.lua:5: libfive.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when I try `local lib = ffi.load( "five" )` instead of `ffi.load( "./five.so" )`.